# What exactly is 'Google Chrome Helper (GPU)'?

Tags: google-chrome

What exactly is 'Google Chrome Helper (GPU)', and (aside from having two chrome instances open with ~15 tabs in each), is there anything I can do to reduce its memory use? Is its (high) memory use affected by me *not* having a dedicated GPU?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What exactly is 'Google Chrome Helper (GPU)'

It could be a chrome tab, extension, process, or a subframe.

> and (aside from having two chrome instances open with ~15 tabs in each), is there anything I can do to reduce its memory use?

close tabs and use a single instance of chrome

> Is its (high) memory use affected by me not having a dedicated GPU?

nope

#### Answer to followup question about determining the cost of specific helpers:

Open Chrome Task Manager via Shift + Esc and look for tasks that are consuming high memory.

[image]

Comment: "It could be a chrome tab, extension, process, subframe." - are there ways of isolating which tab? No one tab is doing anything out of the ordinary, but >2GB ram is a lot, even for chrome. If I can isolate and close it, that would free up those consumed GB?

Comment: your solution (checking Chrome Task Manager) solved perfectly. It turned out 3 google sheets (all very tiny spreadsheets) were using > 1GB each (!!!)